# What is the effect of using auto increment key in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

When i consider the structure of table, i'm hesitating if i should use the `auto increment key` as the primary key in my table. I can't find the good effect of using the auto increment key and the bad effect of not using auto increment key. Someone say use `auto increment key` can increase the query performance. Is that right?

Comment: For this kind of question, always tell us what RDBMS product you are using.

Comment: as what I've seen in sql server, the `Clustered Index` on primary key increase the performance when you query with primary key.

Comment: I don't think having an auto increment PK versus having an ordinary PK of the same column type with *exactly the same data* inserted in exactly the same order will make any difference in how the table is stored or accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Someone say use auto increment key can increase the query performance

Well, that is true if the key is an index (most likely the primary key). This will speed up performance when querying for that specific primary key field, since it can obtain the row number in the actual storage much faster using an index.

Another benefit is having a general identification of the row.

Of course, a general primary key does all that, but now you don't have to make up a value for that field yourself. It's all done for you.

Comment: A primary key always has an index. What difference does it make it it was derived by auto increment or not?

Comment: @stamaimer: Identification of the row.

Comment: and what's the original intension of deign `auto increment key`

Comment: @stamaimer: See the update. You don't have to make up an number yourself, the DB does that for you.

Comment: @PatrickHofman if i already have another field which can identify each row, should i set the `auto increment key`

Comment: No, it's not mandatory. If you have a product table for example and the product id's are created by a person instead of the database (auto_increment) that is okay.

Comment: @stamaimer: need more help?

Comment: @stamaimer: Anything withholding you to accept the answer?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I think there might be deep intension of designing auto increment key.